# how to order mysql result based on the json key of a json object stored in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, json

jSonColoumn -  data type (TEXT)

sample rows

```
{"scheduledTime":"2014-01-29 19:55:00"}  
{"scheduledTime":"2014-01-29 22:55:00"}    
{"scheduledTime":"2014-01-29 15:55:00"}
{"scheduledTime":"2014-01-29 08:55:00"}
```

i need to sort this result with the "scheduledTime" key of the json object stored in the column "jSonColoumn". (Simply i need to order by the result based on the "scheduledTime" key of the json)

Thanks

Comment: its that realy sql? from what sql does this data come? did u try `order by` ? please improve your question

Comment: @Melon: I think it is just a `text` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [some MySQL JSON functions](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/).

Like this:

```
select json_extract(columnX, '{"scheduledTime"}')
```

Comment: select json_extract(columnX, '$.scheduledTime')